# Partial function application in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm writing a function to partially-apply arguments to functions, such that

```
(define mapeven (partial-apply map even?))
(mapeven (list 1 2 3 4)) ; '(#f #t #f #t)
```

To that end, I have

```
(define (partial-apply* func . args)
  (define (apply-one func arg)
    (λ args (apply func (cons arg args))))
  (foldl (λ (new carry) (apply-one carry new)) func args))
```

which seems to work fine. However, I'd also like to be able to "skip" args (probably by use of a sentinel value, like 'λ). I.E.:

```
(define apply-to-four (partial-apply map 'λ (list 1 2 3 4))
(apply-to-four even?) ; '(#f #t #f #t)
```

That is to say, when partial-apply encounters 'λ, it does NOT bind a value to that position, instead leaving it as a free variable. And when a partially applied function is called, first it will fill in arguments skipped by this mechanism of 'λ, then it will apply any remaining arguments to the end.

To this end, I have written:

```
(define (partial-apply func . args)
  (define (apply-one func arg)
    (if (equal? arg 'λ)
        (λ args (λ (x) (apply func (cons x args)))))
        (λ args (apply func (cons arg args)))))
  (foldl (λ (new carry) (apply-one carry new)) func args))
```

However, it doesn't work.

```
> (define apply-to-4 (partial-apply map 'λ (list 1 2 3 4)))
> (apply-to-4 even?)
#<procedure>
```

It seems like the problem is in the affirmative branch of the if statement, but I'm having trouble nailing it down. Any advice?

Comment: You're doing this "just for fun", right? Because [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html) already has a `cut` macro that does what you need: `(define apply-to-four (cut map <> '(1 2 3 4)))`

Comment: I wasn't aware, but even still I'd like to understand how it works, and write my own to do that.

Comment: So read that page. It describes everything you need to know to implement it. :-) The reference implementation is also worth checking out.